# How to Make two Column of Popular post widget

Tags: html, css

I want to add a CSS which help me in displaying blogger Popular post widget in two-column. Suppose I am displaying 10 posts in it, so it should display like 5 posts in one column and 5 in other. Can anyone help?
I am using this CSS

```
.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail{margin:0 10px 0 25px !important;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;overflow:hidden}
.PopularPosts .item-snippet{font-family:Domine; font-size:12px;margin-top:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;}
.PopularPosts ul li img{    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;}
.PopularPosts .widget-content ul li{overflow:hidden;padding:15px 0;width:700px; margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;   border-right: 0px solid #000; border-left: 0px solid #000;}
.sidebar .PopularPosts .widget-content ul li:first-child{padding-top:0;    border-top:none;}
.PopularPosts ul li a{    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.4px;
    line-height: 18px;}
.PopularPosts ul li a:hover{color:$(color.theme)}
.PopularPosts .item-title{margin:0;padding:0}
.PopularPosts .item-title .popular_span{color:#C4C4C4;font-size:13px;font-style:normal;line-height:21px;margin-top:3px}
```

Comment: Ashish, I'm afraid the content of your question doesn't provide us with enough information to help you. We cannot use the CSS you provided to reproduce locally. Maybe you can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to recreate your setup and then update your question. Your chances of receiving help will be much higher.

Comment: It is a CSS od popular post widget which is available for blogger template. I can't use jsfiddle.net  as this widget only work to display the most viewed article in blogger. If you tell I can upload XML file of the template I am using